# AS3 TextArea click handling

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, textarea

I am having trouble with handling a click event on a TextArea. I'm developing a mobile app using Flash Mobile. I would like to display a default text in the area and make it disappear when the user selects the field.

The issue is, that the event is thrown only when I click on the border of the TextArea. It never happens when a selection cursor is active. I also tried to add a false editable property to notesInput and set it to true in the handler and it didn't help.

```
private function notesClickHandler(event:Event):void{
            notesInput.text = "";
            notesInput.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, notesClickHandler);
            form.invalidElements;
        }

<TextArea id="notesInput" text="Poznámky.."
                          height="150" width="100%"
                          verticalScrollPolicy="auto"/>
```

Thank you guys for your time and your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **prompt text** which will fulfill your requirement:

```
<s:TextArea id="notesInput"
            prompt="Default Text"
            height="150" width="100%"
            verticalScrollPolicy="auto"/>
```

It will not clear the default text when you focus in. But you can make that happen by clearing **prompt text** when you focus in the TextArea.

```
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    private function onFocusIn():void
    {
        notesInput.prompt = "";
    }
    private function onFocusOut():void
    {
        notesInput.prompt = "Default Text";
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>
<s:TextArea id="notesInput"
            prompt="Default Text"
            height="150" width="100%"
            verticalScrollPolicy="auto"
            focusIn="onFocusIn()"
            focusOut="onFocusOut()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use an `focusIn` event like this :

```
private function text_area_focusInHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
{
    text_area.text = ''         
}

<s:TextArea id="text_area" x="10" y="10" focusIn="text_area_focusInHandler(event)" text="default text"/>
```